# about gen_udp for erlang multibrodcast

Tags: erlang

i have some erlang code, i don't understand this code `{ add_membership, { Addr, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } } },` what's the meaning of `0.0.0.0`.

```
Addr = {226,0,0,1},
Opts = [ { active, true },
       { ip, Addr },
       { add_membership, { Addr, { 0, 0, 0, 0 } } },
       { multicast_loop, true },
       { reuseaddr, true },
       list ],
{ ok, RecvSocket } = gen_udp:open (Port, Opts),
```

anyone can tell me the meaning of `0.0.0.0`?

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` is the wildcard IP address. The machine might have several IP addresses, e.g. if it has several network interface cards.

With the `add_membership` option you register a multicast address (`Addr`) and say that incoming packets from any network interface (`0.0.0.0`) will be forwarded to your application.
You can add a specific IP address instead of `0.0.0.0` if you only want to allow multicast packets from that particular interface.